# Simpliest way to create an API proxy server for a mobile app?

Tags: android, api, caching, amazon-web-services

I am running into an issue with rate-limiting and think I have found a good solution.

I would like to create a server which periodically requests data from 2 different APIs (Twitter, RSS feed) and caches it on the server.  The client would then request the data from the server and display it.  I only have limited experience in server-side development.  Can anyone provide any tips or point me in the right direction in order to implement this.  I was thinking about using Amazon Web Services to host the server? Any pointers are much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this, but if you want to use AWS, you could choose S3 as the place to store a copy of the RSS feed (perhaps in JSON format), and your android ap could just request it from there.

S3 is super cheap, super redundant and super fast - plus you can use http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/ and push out copies to geographically closer regions around the world (for pennies), if you think you would benefit from that reduction in latency (and assuming you have geographically diverse users).

The only part you would still need to do would be a small/simple back-end process that polls the two source API's, on a schedule you determine, and writes the data to S3.

For something like this a micro-EC2 instance would probably be plenty of horsepower and only cost a few dollars per month.

Comment: Thanks for the great response.  I will definitely look into this. I wanted to go with AWS so I could scale it up if needed. SO for the backend process what do you recommend (PHP or is it possibly with node.js?).

Comment: I'd recommend ASP.Net, because that is the tool I know and use :) but PHP would work fine as well - anything that can read the RSS feed, and write to S3 will work fine - it doesn't sound like the background process is very cumbersome or heavyweight, so whatever tool you know should work just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately I am a front end developer so I only know very basic server side stuff. I'll have to brush up on a language.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a bigger privacy concern if you started saving other peoples data yourself (I'm not sure how many people would be ok with you to saving their Twitter data on your server).

I'm sure you can cache Twitter and RSS data locally, and just ask for whatever has changed? which might reduce the number of requests your sending?

Alternatively, you could save the API key your using on a web service and get your apps request that key each time. When you've run into limitations with one API key, just switch to using another? Google actually recommend this method for using their own API's (this way you can revoke an API key easily without having to upload a new app).

Hope that makes sense,

Danielle

Comment: I wouldnt be saving any personal data on the server. Its all stuff accessible via Twitters API it would basically just be a json sring of tweets about a certain subject. I am also currently caching the data locally, I'm just worried about hitting the rate limit if I say have 200 users use the app in a 10 min window. What I want is basically just a relay to the APIs so that they dont execute 200 times in a 10 min window and instead refresh themselves every 20 min or so.